# Htaccess authentication

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a hosting, where I got specified admin panel. On this panel I can set passwords and usernames, and the passwords get encrypted. So my question is:
Is there any way for that to design the authentication?

I mean, when it requires login and password, it pops-up in browser, and I'd like to make this happen ON the website, where I can design it with CSS, not IN the browser. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, any helpful answers gets me closer.

Comment: Please be more specific. What hosting? What admin panel? When you refer to something happening “in the browser”, what do you mean exactly? A screenshot could help.

Comment: Thanks, for the help, in the meantime I got solve for the problem! :) By the way, I meant it "happens" in the browser, it's not on the web page, it's the browser what requests authentication with a pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, beware that the user name and password are sent in clear(base64 encoding) text if you are using "Basic Authentication" and not wrapped with the ssl module.

To achieve what you are trying do, you will have to use "form authentication":

```
<form method="post" action="validate_credentials.php" >
  <table border="1" >
     <tr>
        <td><label for="user">Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="user" id='user'></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><label for="pass" >Password</label></td>
        <td><input name="pass" id='pass' type="password" ></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and here is how the `validate_credentials.php` file looks like:

```
<?php

// Grab User submitted information
$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];

// Stored user name and password
$db_user = "secret_username";
$db_pass = "secret_password";

// Authentication mechanism

if ($username != $db_user and $password != $db_pass) {
     echo"Invalid Credentials, Please try again.";
     exit();
}

if ($username == $db_user and $password == $db_pass) {
    echo"Valid Credentials, You are authenticated.";
    // You can now serve the document that was requested.
}
```

I just tried to keep it simple so that you understand. To feel safe, validate user inputs and don't use clear text passwords in `validate_credentials.php` file, you can google how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this way is much easier now! Now I can move on! :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)